# Extend spdlog for custom type

Tags: c++, spdlog

Is there a way to extend `spdlog` to support a custom struct as an item when formatting using `{}`?

So when I have a

```
struct p {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

p my_p;
```

I want to do

```
spdlog::info("p = {}", my_p);
// after registering some kind of formatter object for {p}
```

instead of

```
spdlog::info("p = (x={}, y={}, z={})", my_p.x, my_p.y, my_p.z);
```

Comment: The global name `_s` is reserved, check for "reserved identifiers in C++". That said, is there a documented way to extend spdlog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include "spdlog/spdlog.h"
#include "spdlog/fmt/ostr.h" // must be included

class some_class {};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const some_class& c)
{ 
  return os << "some_class"; 
}
```

see https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/wiki/1.-QuickStart#log-user-defined-objects

Comment: Somehow missed this completely when looking through the documentation for exactly this ...

Comment: This solution does not work anymore in recent versions of spdlog. It seems you have to specialize a formatter<T> now (following https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#format-api).

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer does not work anymore with newer versions of spdlog, `fmt` now requires specializing `formatter<T>` (see https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#udt for details).

Using your `p` struct this is the formatter:

```cpp
#include <spdlog/fmt/bundled/format.h>

template<>
struct fmt::formatter<p> {
    constexpr auto parse(format_parse_context& ctx) -> decltype(ctx.begin()) {
        return ctx.end();
    }

    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const p& input, FormatContext& ctx) -> decltype(ctx.out()) {
        return format_to(ctx.out(),
            "(x={}, y={}, z={})",
            input.x, input.y, input.z);
    }
};
```

The `parse` method is used to read eventual format specifications, if you don't need them you can simply return `ctx.end()` and skip specifications like in the sample.

Comment: I am on spdlog 1.10.0 (Apr 2022) and the accepted answer still works for me as long as `spdlog/fmt/ostr.h` is included. I wonder if it's fmt that requires this answer, but not spdlog, i.e. if you use fmt without spdlog?

Comment: @aghidini your example does not compile. It must be `input.x, input.y, input.z` instead of `p.` in format.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno what is happened, but `fmt v10.1.1` again supports user-defined-type formatting with the `std::stream`. The only thing which you must add is a formatter specialization inherited from `ostream_formatter`. Previous versions did not require it.

```cpp
template <> struct fmt::formatter<p> : ostream_formatter {};
```

Following is a copy from the user manual:

```cpp
#include <fmt/ostream.h>

struct date {
  int year, month, day;

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const date& d) {
    return os << d.year << '-' << d.month << '-' << d.day;
  }
};

template <> struct fmt::formatter<date> : ostream_formatter {};

std::string s = fmt::format("The date is {}", date{2012, 12, 9});
// s == "The date is 2012-12-9"
```

For details see [std::ostream Support](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#ostream-api)